# How to add a prop from a functional component into a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-class-based-component

I have a prop "language" that comes from my LanguageFlag component that inserts a SVG icon depending on the language (shown below). In a normal functional component I would pass the language through a prop in and then add it in the component as language={language}.

In this case `<LanguageTitleOptions language={this.props.language}/>` I read I should add it this way. But how do I pass the language property to my LandingPage component?

**LandingPage component**

```
class LandingPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
formVisible: false,
earlyAccessSuccessVisible: false,
isMobile: this._getIsMobile(),
};
}


return (
<div className="buttons">
   <LanguageTitleOptions
      **language={this.props.language}/>**
      <LanguageSelector/>
   </LanguageTitleOptions>
</div>
```

**LanguageFlag component**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import SpainFlag from "./SpainFlag";
import UKFlag from "./UKFlag";

const FLAGS = {
    es: SpainFlag,
    en: UKFlag,
};

const LanguageFlag = ({ language, ...otherProps }) => {
    if (!language) return null;

    const Flag = FLAGS[language];

    return <Flag {...otherProps} />;
};

LanguageFlag.propTypes = {
    language: PropTypes.oneOf(["es", "en"]),
};

export default LanguageFlag;
```

**LandingPageContainer**

```
imports....
....
....
import LandingPage from "./LandingPage";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        rootItemId: state.rootItemId,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onRootItemAvailable: (rootItemId) => {
            history.replace(generateItemPath(rootItemId));
        },
        onEarlyAccessRegistration: () => {
            const anonymousId = getAnonymousId();

            Meteor.call(TRACK_USER_REGISTERED_EMAIL, anonymousId);
        },
    };
};

const LandingPageContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LandingPage);

export default LandingPageContainer;
```

**LanguageTitleOptions component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import LanguageFlag from "/imports/cuadds/client/components/pages/settings/graphics/LanguageFlag";
import { Trans } from "@lingui/macro";

const LanguageTitleOptions = ({ language, className, children }) => {
    const menu = useRef();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    const onWindowClick = (e) => {
        // close menu if user clicked outside language selector menu element
        if (!menu.current.contains(e.target)) {
            setOpen(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (open) {
            window.addEventListener("click", onWindowClick);
        }
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("click", onWindowClick);
        };
    }, [open]);

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
            <div className={className}>
                <Trans>Language:</Trans>
                <LanguageFlag language={language} width={18} style={{ marginLeft: 9 }} />
                <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div ref={menu}>{open && children}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default LanguageTitleOptions;
```

Comment: what is `LanguageTitleOptions` component?

Comment: Can you give the parent of `LandingPage` please?

Comment: @Konstantin It is the LandingPageContainer (I just added it at the bottom)

Comment: @TaghiKhavari the LanguageTitleOptions is a dropdown menu with two languages which you can select.

Comment: how are `LandingPage` and `LanguageFlag` related? if `LandingPage` is not a descendants from `LanguageFlag` you cant pass it.

Comment: @buzatto Inside the landing page I have a language component which changes the language when you select it. in the title of that component (languageTitleOptions) a flag normally displays depending on the language. 

Inside the component LanguageTitleOptions I have the languageFlag component which takes in language={language}.

Answer (score 1):

You pass props the same way as to functional components:

```
<LandingPage language={...}/>
```